# How do I create a "not" filter in python for pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have this large dataframe I've imported into pandas and I want to chop it down via a filter.  Here is my basic sample code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas import Series, DataFrame

df = DataFrame({'A':[12345,0,3005,0,0,16455,16454,10694,3005],'B':[0,0,0,1,2,4,3,5,6]})

df2= df[df["A"].map(lambda x: x > 0) & (df["B"] > 0)]
```

Basically this displays bottom 4 results which is semi-correct.  But I need to display everything BUT these results.  So essentially, I'm looking for a way to use this filter but in a "not" version if that's possible.  So if column A is greater than 0 AND column B is greater than 0 then we want to disqualify these values from the dataframe.  Thanks

Comment: Read the documentation on boolean masking here : http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing.  You can use `~` as "not" `df2= df[~df["A"].map(lambda x: x > 0) & (df["B"] > 0)]`

Comment: this is a step in the right direction but it leaves me only with 2 records instead of 5

Comment: Sorry, the snippet I posted needs to be applied to the entire mask, not just the first one. `df[~(df["A"].map(lambda x: x > 0) & (df["B"] > 0))]`

Comment: Why can't you then do the reverse? if column A is less than 0 or column b is less then 0

Comment: @Thomas Tu that works thank you!!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

No need for map function call on Series "A".

Apply [De Morgan's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws):

**"not (A and B)" is the same as "(not A) or (not B)"**

```
df2 = df[~(df.A > 0) | ~(df.B > 0)]
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for the `map` implementation. You can just reverse the arguments like ...

```
df.ix[(df.A<=0)|(df.B<=0),:]
```

Or use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) without `ix`:

```
df[(df.A<=0)|(df.B<=0)]
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use: wrap everything in a bracket and use a ~ (tilde) outside. in place of not.

```
df[~((df['A'] >0) & (df['B']>0))]
```

answer:

```
    A       B
0   12345   0
1   0       0
2   3005    0
3   0       1
4   0       2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
df2 = df[df["A"].map(lambda x: x <= 0) | (df["B"] <= 0)]
```